# OK Dialog in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I have an activity that starts on demand of the user.
The user can demand it from several activities.

The thing is I want to give the user an explanation before he has to handle that activity.
I thought about creating a Dialog, giving the user only an OK button to tap on.
But It will be ugly because:

1. It has to return a value (in my case there is no value I have to return)
2. The Dialog will have to start the new activity, then when the user presses 'back' button, it will return to the Dialog

Also, if I choose to return to the activity that showed the dialog and start the new activity from there, I'll have to do this in several places (like I explained in the second line of this questions)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 1. but if you call `dismiss()` in the onClickListener that handles your OK button, it will not be shown again after you come back from the started activity when you press the back button.

Do make it easier to reuse the dialog, you should create a custom class that handles the dialog. Then you can easily show the dialog from different activities.